# Is it possible to get item from dictionary using string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to, in runtime get an item from it, using a parameter that has been passed in.

```
var field = @"['IconDescription'].Value";

var dictionary = (defaultOutcome).ToDictionary(xs => xs.Field);

dictionary + field;
```

```
var field = @"['IconDescription'].Value";

var dictionary = (defaultOutcome).ToDictionary(xs => xs.Field);
```

So I need to get the item with key IconDescription from the dictionary and get it's Value property, similar to the following result:

```
dictionary["IconDescription"].Value
```

Comment: There are already two votes to close your question for being unclear. If the dictionary has a key type of `string`, then you can simply address the dictionary as `dictionary["Key"]`, which will return the corresponding value or throw an exception. I sense this isn't what you're asking. If you want to use a string to direct that, you'll have to parse the string yourself.

Comment: I need to get the key using the field variable (it will be a parameter in my method) and it will change

Comment: Where does "field" come from? I mean, why isn't it possible to just pass the key? It's certainly possible using regular expressions to extract the key from `field`, but the reason for doing it is a mystery.

Comment: Do you need parse @"['IconDescription'].Value" and get key name IconDescription from this?

Comment: @SvetlanaMeleshkina, yes that's what I want. What it's field is what I need, the item icondescription and it's value

Comment: see my answer, you can use RegEx for parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for parsing your parameter

```
private string Parse(string input)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^(\\[\\')(\\w+)(\\'\\]\\.Value)");
    var match = regex.Match(input);
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[2].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```